# I'm totally baffled... how do i redirect to both www an non www to a new domain?

Tags: redirect, no-www, iirf

I've recently moved domains successfully however what I didn't realise was that there were two versions of the website: www and non-www

I want to redirect the traffic from my non-www site to my new domain...

This is how the iirf.ini file looks like at the moment:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.foo\.com/? [NC]
RedirectRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bar.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

How do I set it up so that it also redirects the non-www site?

Please help because I'm baffled.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(bar|foo)\.com/? [NC]
RedirectRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bar.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Network Level Solution:
1. Point your external DNS to same public IP of www domain, so that both domains point to same IPs.

eg. www.abc.com - 111.111.111.111
    adb.com - 111.111.111.111

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect both versions in one statement. Well, you probably "could", but it's not the correct way how to do this. Correct way is this:

1) Redirect old domain from www to non-www version (do this in .htaccess file belonging to an **old** domain)

2) Redirect new domain from www to non-www version (do this in .htaccess file belonging to a **new** domain)

3) Redirect old non-www version of the old domain to a new non-www version of new domain (do this in .htaccess file belonging to an **old** domain)

---

So here is the drill:

1) This redirects old domain from www to non-www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) http://olddomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

2) This redirects new domain from www to non-www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.newdomain.com [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

3) This redirects old domain to new domain (both non-www versions):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```